# Make hibernate backquote all table / column names

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, escaping

I am faced with legacy system written to work with MySQL 5.0 and now need to migrate it to MysQL 5.5 (requirement). I found that one column was named `maxvalue`, which seems to be system word in MySQL 5.5. Thus all my Hibernate queries that include this column give syntax error:

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'maxvalue

It seems that Hibernate does not automatically but backquotes ` around the field name. If I extract the query, backquote `` `maxvalue` `` it runs correctly in MySQL 5.5.

I have found [solution](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/) how to explicitly force backquotes for specific field / table. The thing is that I am not sure how many other column names will produce such problem. **Is there a way to tell Hibernate to automatically backquote all table/ column names?** (which will produce valid SQL and I don't know why it does not do that by default for MySQL).

**EDIT**: [This discussion](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2400843) almost makes me believe that what I want is not possible.

Comment: Since hibernate is an open source project.... :)

Comment: @JermaineXu Yes and we all have the time to stop whatever we're actually working on to learn and fix someone else's code...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a [non-documented](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5673) property for this purpose. Use,

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
```

or

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</property>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Now this property is documented at least somewhere. regretfully I am running hibernate 3.3 and it seems this property is introduced in 3.5. I will not be able to validate this property is actually working, but I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: for people using Spring: the application.properties prop is: 'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true'

Comment: "There's no such thing as an undocumented feature. If your users don't know about a feature, its a nonfeature. Get rid of it; it's just complicating the sourcecode." -- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/WhyThisProjectIsSuccessful

Comment: This only add backticks to the table names and db name. Columns are still the same... `insert into 'default_settings' (account, key, value) values (?, ?, ?)`. Problem is with the column name `key`.