# Hibernate reverse engineering: generate hbm.xml with escaped column names (backticks)

Tags: hibernate, orm, reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping

I was wondering if there is a way to generate hibernate mapping files (hbm.xml) with columns escaped (i.e. with backticks).

So instead of

```
<property name="myColumnId" type="java.lang.Long">
```

I would like

```
 <property name="`myColumnId`" type="java.lang.Long">
```

I did see that you can specify

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
```

...(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932136/make-hibernate-backquote-all-table-column-names)) but I'm not sure where to insert that. I've tried inserting it into my hibernate.cfg.xml but did not notice any difference. Is this another option for hibernate to use the literal casing instead of escaping the names in the hbm.xml?

There was a similar question here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2398283

Thank you in advance for any help! :D