# Hibernate throws SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The entity class is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movieDetail")
public class MovieDetailImpl implements MovieDetail {

    @Id
    // primary key
    @Column(name = "idmovieDetail")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "cast")
    private String cast;
    @Column(name = "producer")
    private String producer;
    @Column(name = "director")
    private String director;
    @Column(name = "trailer")
    private URL trailer;
    @Column(name = "photo")
    private URL photo;
    @Column(name = "plot")
    private URL plot;
    @Column(name = "desc")
    private String desc;
    @Column(name = "moreDetails")
    private URL moreDetails;

    // Getters/Setters

}
```

I am trying to persist a `MovieDetail` entity with only `cast` set. Rest of the fields are `null`.

Hibernate throws the below exception:

> 014-08-17 21:47:35 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399:
>   Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
>
> 2014-08-17 21:47:35 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397:
>   Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>
> 2014-08-17 21:47:36 INFO  HibernateTransactionManager:341 - Using
>   DataSource
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@1fba434a]
>   of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
>
> Hibernate: insert into movieDetail (cast, desc, director, moreDetails,
>   photo, plot, producer, trailer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> 2014-08-17 21:47:36 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1064,
>   SQLState: 42000
>
> 2014-08-17 21:47:36 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, director,
>   moreDetails, photo, plot, producer, trailer) values ('testGetAll' at
>   line 1
>
> 2014-08-17 21:47:36 INFO  GenericApplicationContext:873 - Closing
>   org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@40266966:
>   startup date [Sun Aug 17 21:47:34 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy

In my 'database.properties' ,  I have :

> jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

I am using a  MySQL Community Server 5.6.20. and the mysql java driver version dependency defined in maven's pom.xml is

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.28</version>
 </dependency>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You have a column named `desc`, and `desc` is a reserved work in `MySql`, try with another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a column named `desc`, and `desc` is a reserved work in MySql (and many other databases).

You can:

- From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932136/make-hibernate-backquote-all-table-column-names) you can make hibernate escape all column and table names: `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` (in your `persistence.xml`, or hibernate configuration.
- Change the name of the column
- From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa) you can escape only this identifier using:

> @Column(name="\"desc\"")

Also, if is not a legacy database, please consider renaming.