# Special character in table name hibernate giving error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to update the table from Hibernate. My table name has the special character '@' at the beginning of the name. When I am trying to update it its giving me following error.

> > SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [kendo] in context with path [/GanttView] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [Update [@IS_Demand] set sel=1]] with root cause
> >         org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [Update [@IS_Demand] set sel=1]

I don't want to change the name of the table in the database because then I will have to change many things. Is there any way I could access it.
I tried many other combinations like

```
\"@IS_Demand\"  or  '@IS_Demand' or '[@IS_Demand]'
```

Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932136/make-hibernate-backquote-all-table-column-names

Answer (score 1):

try using the escape charater for the same

```
\\@IS_Demand
```

or

```
!@IS_Demand
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property available you need to set.

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
```

For more details,

[AvailableSettings.html#GLOBALLY_QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#GLOBALLY_QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Thank you so much Ankur-singhal i will try using it

Comment: I tried this just now but its not working. I am using hibernate 4.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`