# Maria DB - JPA/Hibernate update query throws an exception due to wrong query generation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I have been working developing on a tool to load/update data into Maria DB using Spring Boot and JPA/Hibernate. I want load data into a table with composite primary keys. Below is what I have tried

**The Primary Key Embedded class, it consistes of two primary keys , key and language**

```
@Embeddable
public class MessageResourcePK implements Serializable {
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4226351093015653675L;

private String language;
private String key;

public MessageResourcePK() {}

public MessageResourcePK(String language, String key) {
    super();
    this.language = language;
    this.key = key;
}

/**
 * @return the language
 */
@Column(name = "LANGUAGE")
public String getLanguage() {
    return this.language;
}

/**
 * @param language the language to set
 */
public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

/**
 * @return the key
 */
@Column(name = "KEY")
public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
}

/**
 * @param key the key to set
 */
 public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean resultat = false;

    if (obj == this) {
        resultat = true;
    } else {
        if (!(obj instanceof MessageResourcePK)) {
            resultat = false;
        } else {
            MessageResourcePK autre = (MessageResourcePK) obj;
            if (!this.language.equals(autre.language)) {
                resultat = false;
            } else {
                if (!this.key.equals(autre.key)) {
                    resultat = false;
                } else {
                    resultat = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultat;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    return (this.language + this.key).hashCode();
 }
```

**The actual table class**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "MESSAGE_RESOURCE")
 @IdClass(MessageResourcePK.class)
 public class MessageResourceTable implements 
 Comparable<MessageResourceTable> {
 /**
 *
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -4226351093015653675L;

 private String language;
 private String key;
 private String message;

 /**
 * @return the language
 */
 @Id
 @Column(name = "LANGUAGE")
 public String getLanguage() {
    return this.language;
 }

 /**
  * @param language the language to set
 */
 public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
 }

 /**
 * @return the key
 */
 @Id
 @Column(name = "KEY")
 public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
 }

/**
 * @param key the key to set
 */
 public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
 }

/**
 * @return the message
 */
 @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
 public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
 }

/**
 * @param message the message to set
 */
 public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(final MessageResourceTable o) {
    return this.language.compareTo(o.getLanguage()) + 
 this.key.compareTo(o.getKey());
 }
```

**The Repository JPA for this**

```
@Repository("MessageResourceService")
@Transactional
public interface MessageResourceService extends 
JpaRepository<MessageResourceTable, MessageResourcePK>{

}
```

The findAll method works fine, but when I try to use save method, it generates the following query

```
update
    message_resource 
set
    message=? 
where
    key=? 
    and language=?
```

But in Maria DB it will not execute, I tried locally with the following query which works fine

```
update message_resource m set m.MESSAGE = 'jjjj' where m.`KEY`='someKey' and 
m.`LANGUAGE`='someLanguage'
```

As the query generated is wrong, it throws **SQLGrammarException** because infront of key there should be something like **m.key**, is there some solution for it. Please don't mark this as duplicate because, i searched through stackoverflow and nobody got the same case like me.

**The application.properties file**

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen 
database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
 org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class
=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext


spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: Could you post the properties? Like the `application.properties` and the `persistence.xml`

Comment: I think it's because `key` is a reserved word, so you have to quote it. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943679/3841161. Also having all the names in uppercase could be the source of your next problem.

Comment: @vc73 - Added the application.properties file

Comment: @coladict - Worked fine, thanks a lot, can you explain about that property?

Comment: It forces Hibernate to always use the quotation markers around database, schema, table, and field names when generating queries. It's necessary when you have table/field names that are also reserved words, which is best to avoid, but when there's over 900 reserved words, it's also pretty difficult.

Comment: @coladict - Thanks a lot, stuck there for half a day